# Caching in .Net Core with BackgroundService fails: "Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count error"

Tags: c#, .net-core, caching, background-service

I have implemented a BackgroundService for caching, following exactly the steps [described by Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/caching#worker-service-caching).
I created the default WebApi project, and replaced the fetching of the photos in the Microsoft code with just generating an array of WeatherForecast objects, as that is already available in the sample project. I removed all HttpClient code as well, including DI stuff.

I configure an interval of 1 minute and when I run the code, the `CacheWorker.ExecuteAsync` method is hit immediately, so all is well. Then, after 1 minute, my breakpoint is hit again only when I hit `Continue`, the app crashes:

```
System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException: Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count.
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release(Int32 releaseCount)
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release()
   at WebApiForBackgroundService.CacheSignal`1.Release() in D:\Dev\my work\WebApiForBackgroundService\WebApiForBackgroundService\CacheSignal.cs:line 18
   at WebApiForBackgroundService.CacheWorker.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in D:\Dev\my work\WebApiForBackgroundService\WebApiForBackgroundService\CacheWorker.cs:line 61
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.TryExecuteBackgroundServiceAsync(BackgroundService backgroundService)
'WebApiForBackgroundService.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.11\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host: Critical: The HostOptions.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior is configured to StopHost. A BackgroundService has thrown an unhandled exception, and the IHost instance is stopping. To avoid this behavior, configure this to Ignore; however the BackgroundService will not be restarted.
```

The code of my worker service:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace WebApiForBackgroundService;

public class CacheWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
    private readonly CacheSignal<WeatherForecast> _cacheSignal;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public CacheWorker(
        CacheSignal<WeatherForecast> cacheSignal,
        IMemoryCache cache) =>
        (_cacheSignal, _cache) = (cacheSignal, cache);

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _cacheSignal.WaitAsync();
        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                WeatherForecast[]? forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                    })
                    .ToArray();

                _cache.Set("FORECASTS", forecasts);
            }
            finally
            {
                _cacheSignal.Release();
            }

            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception occurs when calling `_cacheSignal.Release()`, during the 2nd loop, and it's thrown by the CacheSignal class:

```
namespace WebApiForBackgroundService;

public class CacheSignal<T>
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);
    public async Task WaitAsync() => await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    public void Release() => _semaphore.Release(); // THROWS EXCEPTION DURING 2ND LOOP
}
```

And finally my service:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace WebApiForBackgroundService;

public sealed class WeatherService : IWeatherService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly CacheSignal<WeatherForecast> _cacheSignal;

    public WeatherService(
        IMemoryCache cache,
        CacheSignal<WeatherForecast> cacheSignal) =>
        (_cache, _cacheSignal) = (cache, cacheSignal);

    public async Task<List<WeatherForecast>> GetForecast()
    {
        try
        {
            await _cacheSignal.WaitAsync();

            WeatherForecast[] forecasts =
                (await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(
                    "FORECASTS", _ =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(Array.Empty<WeatherForecast>());
                    }))!;

            return forecasts.ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            _cacheSignal.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so two things, 1 is a background service (BackgroundService) another is just some "service" class (WeatherService) these two things probably work in complete different ways, regardless you do not state how WeatherService is consumed. If i was you i would look into LazyCache, seems like it would solve your problem. not enough detail and also conflicting bits. I recomment removing the SemaphoreSlim and re-thinking your approach. in the background service version ist the loop which is calling it again, but this is single threaded aka no need for SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: Interesting point there, @Seabizkit, will look into that. There are probably easier ways to implement caching. The actual production code is slightly more complicated and this seems to be a common caching approach, provided by Microsoft and already in place in our codebase so I wanted/needed to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems to be faulty. It seems that idea was to check if nobody uses the cache before it is set for the first time as stated in [the article itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/caching#worker-service-caching):

**Important:** you need to override `BackgroundService.StartAsync` and call await `_cacheSignal.WaitAsync()` in order to prevent a race condition between the starting of the `CacheWorker` and a call to `PhotoService.GetPhotosAsync`.

So try changing the `ExecuteAsync` to the following:

```
public sealed class CacheWorker : BackgroundService
{
    // ...

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var first = true;
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Updating cache.");
            try
            {
                //...
            }
            finally
            {
                if(first)
                {
                    first = false;
                    _cacheSignal.Release();
                }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Otherwise you will have endless loop which will try to release semaphore every time while it can have maximum 1 slot (hence the exception).

Links:

- [repro with my fix](https://github.com/gurustron/repro-cache-worker)
- [docs PR](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/33589) and [PR with fix](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/33597)

Comment: I now understand the cause of the exception, but in your code `Release` is never called again after the first run, right? Shouldn't it be `WaitAsync` > fetch data > `Release` with every run of the loop?

Comment: @ReinderWit as I understand (as I wrote in the answer) the whole purpose of it to prevent the call to the cache before initialization, so no, it should not.

Comment: @ReinderWit see the note in the doc - _"You need to override BackgroundService.StartAsync and call await _cacheSignal.WaitAsync() in order to prevent a race condition between the starting of the CacheWorker and a call to PhotoService.GetPhotosAsync."_

Comment: @ReinderWit I would argue the whole code is quite bad - `PhotoService.GetPhotosAsync`  blocks the semaphore for the whole method while it is actually needed as a flag check.

Comment: I checked your repo and implemented it in our code; seems to work fine now.

Comment: @ReinderWit also created a [PR to docs](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/33589) it seems that code in docs will implement the similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `StartAsync` you are waiting for the semaphore. You can only have one semaphore at a time `private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);``.

When you have it, `ExecuteAsync` is called. In that method you release the semaphore with `_cacheSignal.Release();`. Then it waits 1 minute and loops again. And the semaphore is once again released. But you already released it once without calling `await _cacheSignal.WaitAsync();` which causes a crash.

You must understand the semaphore's purpose and get where it is best to be released, it is said in the page you sent:

> You need to [...] call await _cacheSignal.WaitAsync() in order to prevent a race condition between the starting of the CacheWorker and a call to PhotoService.GetPhotosAsync.

Alternatively, if you want only a code that works, you can do something like that:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _cacheSignal.Release(); // Releases the semaphore after CacheWorker is started.
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope you understood what I'm saying.

Comment: Should you only call `WaitAsync` once? Or every time before updating the cache?

Comment: I think you should call it only once in `StartAsync`.

Comment: If I only just add `_cacheSignal.Release();` above the while loop, I get the same exception

Comment: Then you might want to move it after `await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);` in the `StartAsync` method. It should still preserve the same mechanic of forcing the call of CacheWorker before PhotoService . @ReinderWit

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a working version, with the hints from other answers (proposed solutions don't seem to work).
My guess is that `WaitAsync` has to be called **every time** before doing a `Release()` but this doesn't happen on subsequent runs of the loop. So I've removed the call in `StartAsync` and added it inside the while loop:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace WebApiForBackgroundService;

public class CacheWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
    private readonly CacheSignal<WeatherForecast> _cacheSignal;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public CacheWorker(
        CacheSignal<WeatherForecast> cacheSignal,
        IMemoryCache cache) =>
        (_cacheSignal, _cache) = (cacheSignal, cache);

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _cacheSignal.WaitAsync();
            
            try
            {
                WeatherForecast[]? forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                    })
                    .ToArray();

                _cache.Set("FORECASTS", forecasts);
            }
            finally
            {
                _cacheSignal.Release();
            }

            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this seems to work. I'd love to hear your comments...

Comment: That completely beats the purpose of the `CacheSignal` usage, as doc state - main reason for it - potential race condition between first cache put and first cache read. The whole purpose of this was the call in `StartAsync` (see the quote from the article I've added to the comments in my answer.)

Comment: As I understand it, the purpose of using the CacheSignal is to prevent access to the cache, when it is going to be instantiated or updated. You're right in that it states that it is important to use it inside StartAsync, but I believe it is equally important to use it again before updating the cache. I tried your setup, but that didn't work either. I'm kinda lost now...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/gurustron/repro-cache-worker) is full working repro for the code taken from the docs snippets, which has the change from my answer and the timeouts/number of iterations. No exceptions thrown.

Comment: As for blocking why cache is updated - usually it should not make much sense, cause the update itself (`_cache.Set("Photos", photos)`) should be atomic. But it can depend on the app logic, you can go either way.