# .NET Hosting IStartup isn't supported

Tags: c#, .net

This is my current `Program` class:

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using DatingApp.API.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace DatingApp.API
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection");
            });

            builder.Services.AddCors(x => x.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                }));

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IDatingRepository, DatingRepository>();

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
                        .GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });

            var app = builder.Build();

            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                    Seed.SeedUsers(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred in migration");
                }
            }



            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline. 
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
                {
                    builder.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.addApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("corsapp");

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();

            host.Run();

        }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<StartupBase>();
                });
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IStartup isn't supported
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at DatingApp.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Demo\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Program.cs:line 54

It is supposed to run and migrate the data to the database but it didn't run

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create host and use startup, just create scope from the app.Services:

```
using(var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    // use context
}
```

As for `IStartup` - check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76204883/2501279).

Comment: I am looking at a similar situation. But I need to boot my IHostedService at `Run()` such that it is up and running when I start a singleton which is consumed by my controllers. Do I just do the same and run the `StartAsync()` before run. Is there a cancelation token for the host service that I can grab?

Comment: @TaylorKendall personally I would go with the demonstrated approach, resolve the dependency and call the init code before calling `Run` on the host (note that in this case I would recommend to split `StartAsync` of the hosted service and actual initialization). In some cases you can go with synchronization approach (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75156466/2501279) and links there), i.e. you use some synchronization primitive which will signal when the hosted service is ready and monitor it in appropriate places. But to say anything more concrete actual code is needed =)